# Where in Cambodia can I get a visa for Vietnam?

Tags: visas

I am going from Cambodia to Phu Quoc, Vietnam, via Ha Tien, and will be staying in Phu Quoc for 17 days. Where is the best place to get a visa to enter Vietnam?

Comment: what is your nationality?

Comment: Your question title and message are two different things. The title asks *is it possible* while the message asks the best place to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The Vietnam embassy is in Phnom Penh, and they have consulates in Battambang and Sihanoukville. Whichever is closest would be the "best" place. They all charge the same amount and take the same amount of time to process the visa.